# Can't open products in frontend

Tags: product, ce-1.9.1.0

i recently changed the theme on my commerce.

When i try to open a product in frontend, magento give me this error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:69:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:2898:"#0 /home/www/app/design/frontend/em0131/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(62): Varien_Object->__call('_isSecure', Array)
#1 /home/www/app/design/frontend/em0131/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(62): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->_isSecure()
#2 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/www/app/d...')
#3 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0131...')
#4 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 /home/www/app/design/frontend/em0131/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(72): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/www/app/d...')
#12 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0131...')
#13 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#19 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#20 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#21 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#22 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/www/index.php(70): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:37:"/it/622av-pettini-avorio-0020002.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"it";}
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It potentially looks like your theme is throwing an error due to a secure link problem, the issue is pointing to line 62 in your /default/template/catalog/view.phtml file.